# Detecting the end of DMA transfer in the Ethernet card.

Tags: rust, driver, linux-device-driver, ethernet, device-driver

I am trying to write a toy kernel in Rust following some blogs online and am using qemu as a hardware emulator. I have configured qemu so that the network card is RTL8139. I am trying to achieve a simple packet transfer.

The device driver structure looks like this

```
Rtl8139 {
  config_1: port(0x52),
  command_register: port(0x37),
  transmit_address: [port(0x20), port(0x24), port(0x28), port(0x2c)],
  transmit_status:  [port(0x10), port(0x14), port(0x18), port(0x1c)],
  id: [port(0), port(1), port(2), port(3), port(4), port(5)],
  descriptor: 0
}
```

where port(X) represent the IO port at an offset of X from the io-base of the device.

The code for packet transfer is as follows

```
fn put_frame(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> Result<usize, u32> {
    self.transmit_address[self.descriptor].out32(buf.as_ptr() as u32); 
    self.transmit_status[self.descriptor].out32(0xfff & (buf.len() as u32));
    while (self.transmit_status[self.descriptor].in32() & 0x8000) == 0 { 
    }
    self.descriptor = (self.descriptor + 1) % 4 ;
    Ok(buf.len())
}
```

The `self.descriptor` tells which port to use among the four ports for transfer. 
In the above code.The first step shows, writing the base address of the data to be transferred into the `transmit_address` port and the range of this data in `transmit_status`. I suppose this will initiate the DMA from that address onto the CPU. And he([here](https://github.com/QuiltOS/QuiltOS)) is using the while loop to somehow detect the end of DMA.

My question is how does the ethernet card communicate the end of DMA to the device driver?

The code is not mine. I referred [QuiltOS](https://github.com/QuiltOS/QuiltOS) for most of it.

Comment: It would appear the Ethernet card causes the `in32()` to toggle the 16th bit when it's finished, based on that while loop. What exactly is the question?